# Find out the most I/O loaded directory

Tags: windows, performance-monitoring, io

Looking for ways to find out the most I/O loaded directory in windows. 
similar to the following in linux to pin point the problem/bottleneck directory.

```
iostat -p 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Disk Usage (du.exe) utility from sysinternals (now owned by Microsoft).  Not sure if it has exactly what you want out of the box, but I bet you could script it otherwise.

Here's the link to the Application site: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651

Here's the command usage from that site:

Usage: du [-c] [-l  | -n | -v] [-u] [-q]

-c  Print output as CSV.
-l  Specify subdirectory depth of information (default is all levels).
-n  Do not recurse.
-q  Quiet (no banner).
-u  Count each instance of a hardlinked file.
-v  Show size (in KB) of intermediate directories.